# Storing values in array/arraylist in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

I have one jmeter variable defined in jsr223 sampler for two users. Is it possible to store those two values in one array?

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

> Properties are not the same as variables. Variables are local to a thread; properties are common to all threads, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function.

So if you want to share an "array" between several Threads you can use the following approach:

```
def list = []

list.add('foo')
list.add('bar')

props.put('list', list)
```

then you can refer `foo` as `props.get('list')[0]` and `bar` as `props.get('list')[1]` where required.

More information on this `props` shorthand and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) components: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)

Comment: Ok using property function is fine..But my problem is that..i am storing current timestamp in a variable t1 using jsr223 sampler and number of threads i have given as 3..so jsr 223 sampler will run three times for three users..now all three t1 values i want to store in an array..how to do that?